# Reading battery level/voltage via USB port

Tags: usb, battery, charging, hardware

I'm interested in creating a device that needs to externally monitor the battery level or voltage of the phone via the USB port. I haven't had much experience with the inner workings of Android, but I do know that apps have access to the battery manager, but I'm wondering if, **during charging, is it possible to obtain data (at least the voltage reading) about the battery via USB without having to install/create an app that reads and sends the data?**

Comment: Hardware that is connected between the charging adapter and device is perhaps the only way of you don't want an app. Such hardware is available, though I haven't used it

Comment: Via adb you should be able to query the battery data: See this for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274720/is-it-possible-to-query-device-state-ie-battery-charge-remaining-via-adb-shel